# How to execute an equivalent function of Xcode's Instruments > "File Activity" in shell?

Tags: terminal, xcode, dtrace

I need to be able to show and capture the same output that `Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app` captures while in Terminal.app (in the shell).  Is there a `dtrace` function / script, or some such equivalent, that can be run in order to capture this data directly?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `fs_usage` with `-f filesys` or `diskio` options?

> The fs_usage utility presents an ongoing display of system call usage information pertaining to filesystem activity.  It requires root privileges due to the kernel tracing facility it uses to operate.  By default, the activity monitored includes all system processes except the running fs_usage process, Terminal, telnetd, telnet, sshd, rlogind, tcsh, csh, sh, and zsh.  These defaults can be overridden such that output is limited to include or exclude a list of processes specified by the user.